# Strange commutator like expression.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a name/ interesting properties for the combination $ \left\{ A,B \right\}_{new} =A^TB-B^TA$ for two square matrices $A,B$? It's basic properties are:

Antisymmetry;

Two matrices "commute" in the sense $ \left\{ A,B \right\}_{new} =0$ iff $A^TB$ is symmetric.

There doesn't appear to be a generalisation of the Jacobi identity, though I might be wrong here. Is there a setting in which this object would arise naturally?